# How do you divide the whole table by a number?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table which shows some data for 90 days period

| Project | Volume | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5003 | 9039 | 8135 |
| 9095 | 16432 | 14789 |
| 25161 | 45458 | 40912 |

I want to use a parameter to easily change the values in the table to reflect 30 days, 60 days, or whatever number of days. So I need to be able to divide to the whole table by this selected parameter. I tried to do this with an if formula but because each cell has a calculation within it self I wasn't successful. E.g volume is calculated by =B1/55.35*100

The formula I tried = ==IF(C1=90,C5,C1*C5/90)B5/55.35*100

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the raw data this table is pulling from and explain the cells you reference in your formula? That will help us get you a better answer faster :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your formatting for the formula is off. And I'm assuming C1 is the cell for the number of days.

If all of the cells in this region are calculated values, or placed there by a formula, all it will take is modifying that IF statement you provided.

If some of the values, like Project, are manually entered numbers, it makes it a bit more tricky to update those numbers in place. You would have to modify the formula each time you wanted to update the value. In that case, you might consider adapting this to display the per-day values in a separate range so you could manually enter those raw numbers without having to edit the formula in the display range.

For the example you gave, try `=if(C1 <> 0, (100*B1/55.35)/C1, 100*B1/55.35)`

If you have entered a value for the number of days, it will divide the base calculation by the contents of C1. If not, it will just present the result of the base calculation.

For each cell in the range, you will need to replace "100*B1/55.35" in the formula above with whatever the actual calculation is currently.

If you are entering raw numbers in some of the fields and want to display the per-day amounts in a separate range, you would just change the formula above in the display cell to refer to the data source cell instead of the calculation.